# Using hostname only instead of FQDN in certificate

Tags: ssl-certificate, certificate, certificate-authority, self-signed-certificate

Can a localhost's name be used on a self signed certificate  and used internally for the applications running on the same localhost?

I am just trying to test my applications with certificates.

Forgive my ignorance I am new to deploying certs.

Comment: Depends on whether those applications are willing to accept a self-signed certificate.

Comment: Why you ever need to use a localhost certificate? Certificate on localhost provides zero benefits because all traffic is passed through a software loopback adapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any hostname and IP-address in self signed certificates.

--

Note that using encryption to communicate between services running on the same host provides no security benefit at all and only creates additional overhead...